# Can I sync non Amazon books from the iPad Kindle app to a PC?

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows, kindle

I downloaded a mobi book directly to my iPad to the Kindle app, which does not sync with Amazon.  I read the post "Syncing non-Amazon purchased eBooks between Kindle, iPad, and iPhone 3"

(on: [Syncing non-Amazon purchased eBooks between Kindle, iPad, and iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/syncing-non-amazon-purchased-ebooks-between-kindle-ipad-and-iphone/71783#71783?newreg=c61ccc6df1e4481eabdc09b928dba319))

which mentions a "Send to Kindle for Mac" you can download on your mac.  I have two problems using the advice above:

1. The book is on my ipad, not my computer, and there doesn't seem to be a "Send to Kindle for iPad" app, and
2. I don't have a Mac, I have a PC.

What do I need to get the book off the iPad and on to the PC?

Comment: There might be an answer on http://ebooks.stackexchange.com or if not I think that is a better site as this is more to do with Kindle infrastructure than OS X

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the Amazon infrastructure rather than Apple hardware